# Working with CMake in a library

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I'm working with a library which presents, as many other libraries I suppose, a lot of directories. In particular, there is the directory "tutorials" in which I found some exercises in order to get confident with these new tools. Now, who wrote these tutorials asks the new user to modify the codes in order to solve different exercises.

So for example, from "example_01" (inside "tutorial" directory) I created a new directory called "example_01ex1" (inside "tutorial", too). Then, I modified the code as asked by the tutorial.

At this point I don't know how to proceed. Inside the directory "example_01" there is a CMakeLists.txt file which I copied and then modified. But when I write at terminal "cmake ." from the new directory I get errors.

In this kind of situation it is necessary everytime control all the CMakeLists.txt files? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You should not change CMakes in a library i suppose. Give it a try with cmake-gui and check, wheather you can compile examples/library. I guess you can.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. If you encountered errors running CMake, maybe you can add them in your question.

Comment: When I want to test one of the tutorials' codes I just have to write 'make' in the specific directory 'example0x'. What I'd like to know is if I have to make some modification to the different CMakeLists.txt files that there are in the library or just create a CMakeLists.txt for my exercise in the specific directory I've just created.

Comment: I guess, you need to modify existing CMakeLists.txt for an excercise and add new target to it, that would build new code.